# Python 2.7 + Django + MySQL-python error

Tags: mysql, django, python-2.7, pip, mysql-python

I installed Python 2.7, Django 1.5.5, MySQL 5.5 on Ubuntu. Then I tried to install SQL driver for python :

```
sudo pip install MySQL-python
```

and the result was

```
Downloading/unpacking MySQL-python
Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement MySQL-python
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for MySQL-python
Storing debug log for failure in .pip/pip.log
```

What could be the problem?

I tried:
    sudo easy_install MySQL-python

with the result:

```
> Searching for MySQL-python Reading
> http://pypi.python.org/simple/MySQL-python/ Download error on
> http://pypi.python.org/simple/MySQL-python/: [Errno -3] Temporary     
> failure in name resolution -- Some packages may not be found! Reading
> http://pypi.python.org/simple/MySQL-python/ Download error on
> http://pypi.python.org/simple/MySQL-python/: [Errno -3] Temporary
> failure in name resolution -- Some packages may not be found! Couldn't
> find index page for 'MySQL-python' (maybe misspelled?) Scanning index
> of all packages (this may take a while) Reading
> http://pypi.python.org/simple/ Download error on
> http://pypi.python.org/simple/: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name
> resolution -- Some packages may not be found! No local packages or
> download links found for MySQL-python error: Could not find suitable
> distribution for Requirement.parse('MySQL-python')
```

Comment: Did you tried "easy_install MySQL-python" ? (you need to do "apt-get install python-dev" if you didnt have python dev installed)

Comment: Looks like problem in package name resolution and it doesn't matter what way I do it.

Answer (score 1):

The correct command is:

```
sudo ap-get install python-mysqldb
```

Comment: `sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb` worked only after cleanup. First I downloaded .deb package from repository to local disk(other repository than my default), than failed to install it. Later I made `sudo apt-get remove ./python-mysqldb_1.2.3-1build1_i386.deb`. This cleanup worked for unknown reason. Finally `sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb` worked.

Comment: @ph7: Then you should now be able to `pip install MySQL-python`